# awslocal: command not found error after installing awscli-local

Tags: pip, aws-cli

I'm trying to install awslocal but it doesn't seem to work as planned. I've done the required installation with the `pip install awscli-local` command which looks like working. But when trying any awslocal command after this, I get the `awslocal: command not found` error.
I'm currently running on Ubuntu 22.04.3 LTS, pip version 22.0.2, aws-cli/2.9.23, Python 3.10.12.
Any idea what might cause the issue ?

Comment: I don't know where `awslocal` is installed but did you open a new terminal/SSH session to test, in case it modified your PATH?

Comment: I did try to open a new terminal without any success... But today it worked when I turned my computer back on. If you post an answer, I'll gladly accept it, thank you !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the most obvious cause of "command not found" right after installing some new software is that the installation needed to modify your PATH to include the location of the new binary/script. On Linux systems, this sometimes means that the installer script modifies one or more of your shell startup scripts e.g. `.bashrc` to append the new app's path to your PATH environment variable.

If that's the case, you have to [source](https://ss64.com/bash/source.html) your startup script (e.g. `. ~/.bashrc`) or simply close and re-open your terminal shell (or you can reboot).